# Using ffmpeg to Stretch the Contrast of a Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to implement what was suggested here: [ffmpeg: adaptively stretch contrast](https://superuser.com/questions/725716/ffmpeg-adaptively-stretch-contrast)

The method I thought of is:

1. Separate the L, U and V channels.
2. Apply histeq to the L channel.
3. Recombine the channels.

I'm new to ffmpeg, so I've been able to do 1 and 2, but not sure how to implement #3. What I have so far is:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf extractplanes=y,histeq=strength=0.3:intensity=1 out.mkv
```

Which extracts the L channel and autocontrasts it, but I'm not sure how to recombine it with the U and V channels. Maybe use `mergeplanes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mkv -filter_complex "extractplanes=y+u+v[y][u][v];   \
[y]histeq=strength=0.3:intensity=1[lumaeq];   \
[lumaeq][u][v]mergeplanes=0x001020:yuv420p[out]" -map "[out]" out.mkv
```

The `extractplanes` filter needs to extract each channel (y+u+v[y][u][v]), which can later be combined with `mergeplanes`.

**Note** that I stated format of the output explicitly to be yuv420p, because my input material is of the same format.
**Note** that I used your strengths and values for the `histeq` filter, which made my "normal" footage completely unusable. That is not to say that it will not work on badly shot footage. But even a value of `histeq=strength=0.1:intensity=0.5` was right at the edge of usability.  This is because histeq is a **global filter** and applying to one channel is not optimal process. In any case you can use the `curves` filter to individually target channels as well.

But the **principle of splitting and merging** is as above.